# Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I have an asp.net application in which I am using linq for data manipulation. While running, I get the exception "Sequence contains no matching element".

```
if (_lstAcl.Documents.Count > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= _lstAcl.Documents.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string id = _lstAcl.Documents[i].ID.ToString();                           
        var documentRow = _dsACL.Documents.First(o => o.ID == id);
        if (documentRow !=null)
        {

            _lstAcl.Documents[i].Read = documentRow.Read;
            _lstAcl.Documents[i].ReadRule = documentRow.ReadRule;

            _lstAcl.Documents[i].Create= documentRow.Create;
            _lstAcl.Documents[i].CreateRule = documentRow.CreateRule;

            _lstAcl.Documents[i].Update = documentRow.Update;
            _lstAcl.Documents[i].UpdateRule = documentRow.UpdateRule;

            _lstAcl.Documents[i].Delete = documentRow.Delete;
            _lstAcl.Documents[i].DeleteRule = documentRow.DeleteRule;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Well, I'd expect it's this line that's throwing the exception:

```
var documentRow = _dsACL.Documents.First(o => o.ID == id)
```

[`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) will throw an exception if it can't find any matching elements. Given that you're testing for null immediately afterwards, it sounds like you want [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), which returns the default value for the element type (which is null for reference types) if no matching items are found:

```
var documentRow = _dsACL.Documents.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == id)
```

Other options to consider in some situations are [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) (when you believe there's exactly one matching element) and [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) (when you believe there's exactly one or zero matching elements). I suspect that `FirstOrDefault` is the best option in this particular case, but it's worth knowing about the others anyway.

On the other hand, it looks like you might actually be better off with a join here in the first place. If you didn't care that it would do *all* matches (rather than just the first) you could use:

```
var query = from target in _lstAcl.Documents
            join source in _dsAcl.Document
            where source.ID.ToString() equals target.ID
            select new { source, target };
foreach (var pair in query)
{
    target.Read = source.Read;
    target.ReadRule = source.ReadRule;
    // etc
}
```

That's simpler *and* more efficient IMO.

Even if you *do* decide to keep the loop, I have a couple of suggestions:

- Get rid of the outer `if`. You don't need it, as if Count is zero the for loop body will never execute
- Use exclusive upper bounds in for loops - they're more idiomatic in C#:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < _lstAcl.Documents.Count; i++)
  ```
- Eliminate common subexpressions:

  ```
  var target = _lstAcl.Documents[i];
  // Now use target for the rest of the loop body
  ```
- Where possible use `foreach` instead of `for` to start with:

  ```
  foreach (var target in _lstAcl.Documents)
  ```

Answer (score 46):

Use **FirstOrDefault**. First will never return null - if it can't find a matching element it throws the exception you're seeing.

```
_dsACL.Documents.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == id);
```

Comment: Just to clarify slightly - First *could* return null in general, if your predicate matched null values. It just can't return null here, as `o.ID` would throw a NullReferenceException on a null value.

Answer (score 17):

From the MSDN library:

> The `First<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method throws an exception if source contains no elements. To instead return a default value when the source sequence is empty, use the `FirstOrDefault` method.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who faced this issue while creating a controller through the context menu, reopening Visual Studio as an administrator fixed it.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe using Where() before First() can help you, as my problem has been solved in this case.

```
var documentRow = _dsACL.Documents.Where(o => o.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What has actually helped you here is using .FirstOrDefault() instead of .First() - using .Where(o => o.ID == id).FirstOrDefault() and .FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == id) will be identical.

Comment: @pwdst using the condition in Where clause and then FirstOrDefault without any lambda expression.

Comment: For future readers, the point here is that more code is being written than is necessary. The lambda can be placed in either the `.Where` or the `.FirstOrDefault`, and if you place it in the `FirstOrDefault` call, you can eliminate the `Where` call.