# Sequence contains no matching element error in Linq Statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to debug my method but I don't know what's wrong with it.

There are times that it throws an error and sometime it's okay. I don't know what's wrong.

Here's my method:

```
private void GetWorkingWeek(int month, int year)
    {
        var cal = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;


        var daysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, cal.GetDaysInMonth(year, month));

        var listOfWorkWeeks = daysInMonth
            .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
            .GroupBy(d => cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday))
            .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.First(), g.Last(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)))
            .ToList();
         foreach (var weekGroup in listOfWorkWeeks)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Week{0} = {1} {2} to {1} {3}"
                        , weekNum++
                        , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month)
                        , weekGroup.Item2.Day
                        , weekGroup.Item3.Day);
                }
    }
```

This is the line where the error appear:

```
var listOfWorkWeeks = daysInMonth
            .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
            .GroupBy(d => cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday))
            .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.First(), g.Last(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)))
            .ToList();
```

This is the error:

```
 InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no matching element
```

Comment: I would guess it's either the First() or Last() method throwing the error.  You could try substituting FirstOrDefault() and LastOrDefault() which will instead return null for an empty data set instead of triggering the exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sequence contains no matching element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994336/sequence-contains-no-matching-element)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var listOfWorkWeeks = daysInMonth
        .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
        .GroupBy(d => cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday))
        .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.FirstOrDefault(), g.LastOrDefault(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)))
        .ToList();
```

Try using `FirstOrDefault` and `LastOrDefault` instead of `First` and `Last`, these methods will return the default value of the type they are invoked for if no elements match the lambda expression you provide as a parameter.

In case of `g.FirstOrDefault()`, the default value will be returned if g is empty and in case of `g.LastOrDefault(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)` the default value will be returned if all days are either saturday or sunday.

Comment: 1+ for your explain