# ForEach error when leaving loop

Tags: c#

I have a For each loop that is using linq to get info from the Visit table. It is nested with another For each loop that gets a name to list in the first column:

```
Caregiver | week1 | week2|....
__________|_______|______|....
John Smith|   2   |   3  |....
Mary Jones|   0   |   1  |....
```

It goes for 9 weeks and picks up a "Visit" count in the nested loop. I believe when I leave the inner loop it gives me a NULL error when it reaches the last Caregiver in the outer loop, and has an issue starting again from the top row for the next week (Week2).

I am getting an **InvalidOperationException** on the `Select` statement before I query the Visit table based on my Linq "visits". What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT:** Here is an image of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oVtd.png

```
var phs = from cg in Context.CareGivers
          join cgg in Context.CareGiverGroups on cg.car_gvr_int_id equals cgg.car_gvr_int_id
          join o in Context.Organizations on cgg.org_int_id equals o.org_int_id
          where cg.row_sta_cd.Trim() == "A"
          && cgg.alt_phy_id != null
          && cgg.alt_phy_id.Trim() != String.Empty
          && o.cli_acc_fg.Trim() == "Y"
          && o.org_int_id == 1468461
          select cg;

int r = 1;
int s = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
     start = start.AddDays(i * -7);
     end = start.AddDays(7);

     foreach (var cg in phs)
             {
             // grab the correct exception, this will allow us to figure out where the issue might be
              var visits = cg.CareGiverFunction.First(cgf => cgf.CodeDetail.cod_dtl_ds.Trim() == "Family Physician").VisitCareGiver.Select(vcg => vcg.Visit).AsQueryable();
              visits = visits.Where(v => v.adm_ts >= start && v.adm_ts < end
                       && (v.CodeDetail.cod_dtl_ext_id.Trim() == "I" || v.CodeDetail.cod_dtl_ext_id.Trim() == "V")
                       && v.VisitStatusCdCodeDetail.cod_dtl_ext_id.Trim() != "CANCEL");


               int counter = visits.Count();
               String phys = cg.Person.DisplayName();

               workbook.AddCell(r, 0, phys);
               workbook.AddCell(r, s, counter);
               r++;

              }
              s++;

    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not C!

Comment: Can you post the details of the error message?

Comment: @MikyDinescu I updated the tag just after the post, thank you.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush - Running code now to grab a screen shot.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush - Added image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cg.CareGiverFunction.First() might not be returning a result, this means that the rest of the code you have on that line doesn't have any data to compare against.

Jon Skeet has answered a similar question, I'll direct you to his post as I doubt I'll be able to answer it any better than him: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3994349/543538)

Comment: Thank you for the direction. Ill move onto this next.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Select` statement looks right.  What does not is the `start = start.AddDays(i * -7)`.  I think what you want is `start = start.AddDays(-7)`. Unless start is reinitialized each time at the top of the loop (this may go for `s` as well), you are first going back 7 days, then 14 more, then 21 more, then 28 more.  Perhaps you are running off the beginning of the data returned by the query?

Comment: So on the first column it would be i * -7 (i being 0 at this point), so it would turn out that we would not add any days here. This is correct because the value for Start is actually the set start date. When it increments to the second column it will indeed move to i * -7 (i now being 1) it will add that -7 days. And so on..

Comment: Yes, I did not take into account the first occurrence, which would add no days.  So your code is correctly dealing with the first two runs, which add 0 and -7 days.  What about the next time?  From the point 7 days ahead of the original start, you will now add another -14; the next time another -21, ...  No?