# Radiobutton - Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I maintain a C# Winform desktop app (.Net 4.0), and some users submitted a crash report with the details below. There is no more info, and since the application has many forms I don't even know for sure which form is causing the issue. 
There is no databinding on the form controls.

Radiobuttons are grouped together in a groupbox. I looked at the source code for the radiobutton control, and it looks like that when a radio is checked, a crash occurs when the .net framework tries to uncheck the other sibling radiobuttons (but only sometimes...)

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Thanks

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.PerformAutoUpdates(Boolean tabbedInto)
at System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.set_Checked(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: I suspect a bad LINQ expression.
Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994336/sequence-contains-no-matching-element

Comment: Share the code which cause the exception throw.

Comment: @Hadar The link code is in the .net Framework itself, so I doubt that it is wrong

Comment: @Reza The code throwing the error is in the .net Framework itself

Comment: Don't be fooled by the stack trace.  It's not in the framework, it's in your code.  Either before or after that sequence of calls, likely after.  Look for any events you have wired up to radio buttons...clicks, selection change, etc.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong it was indeed due to linq in my own code, in one of the CheckedChanged  handlers. It's true that the stack trace really got me confused