# Xamarin forms can't release apk error Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, release

In Xamarin.forms when want to release android I get error "Sequence contains no matching element" just when I tick bundle assemblies into native code.
Here's output:

```
2>  Processing: obj\Release\res\values\splashstyle.xml
2>  Processing: obj\Release\res\values\styles.xml
2>Sequence contains no matching element
2>Done building project "MyApp.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: You could read this and please post more detailed information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994336/sequence-contains-no-matching-element

Comment: any luck solving the issue? I get the same problem...